# m3u8 hls vimeo cross domain videojs

Tags: video.js, http-live-streaming, m3u8

I am trying to play a vimeo m3u8 hls video in videojs player. I am getting cross domain error. Can anybody help me.
My code.

```
<video autoplay id="content_video" class="video-js vjs-default-skin"
    poster = "//test.waytogrow.pl/wideo/videojs/posters/android.png" controls preload="auto" width="640"
    height="360">
  <source src="https://player.vimeo.com/external/155002167.m3u8?p=standard&s=1d09b138bbb4218361013c45d706889df4a80fee"
      type="application/x-mpegURL" ></source>

</video>
```

Error
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://player.vimeo.com/external/155002167.m3u8?p=standard&s=1d09b138bbb4218361013c45d706889df4a80fee. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://example.com' is therefore not allowed access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't fix this. Only Vimeo can, by adding CORS headers to the responses. Otherwise you need to host the video elsewhere.